# Color.FromArgb(...); security message

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, windows-runtime

I am defining a Color from argb , ex

```
Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0);
```

In visual studio 2012 , winRT application it says that this is tagged with [security critical] . Are there any reasons why? I tried searching, no results. And no idea why this relates to security.

Update:

Now I notice, not only does FromArgb(...); methods gives this [SECURITY CRITICAL] warning. any of these:

```
c.A = 255;
c.R = 255;
c.G = 0;
c.B = 0;
```

Also does.

Comment: System.Drawing has no relation to WPF so what is the background of the question? What is your intention?

Comment: Intention: I was curious about this security attribute. Or how it would relate to security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Drawing is a wrapper around unmanaged GDI+ code. From my understanding, WinRT does not support GDI+:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithnativecode/thread/0ba00fbd-183f-4df6-afa2-04d0ac14706a

> Native rendering code will need to be done with Direct2D.

Comment: @stakx No idea how many steps are inbetween, but in the end it's indeed a whole bunch of IntPtr's and calls to `System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods` which P/Invokes `[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]`. It's already officially unsupported in ASP.net applications (although in most cases it works), and it seems that for Windows Store apps they killed it for good. `System.Drawing.Color` is actually just a plain, harmless struct, but I think that they just marked the whole namespace as verboten.

Answer (score 2):

Your message **is not a Warning**, is information about method signature attribute.

SECURITY CRITICAL is a code Attribute wich real class name is SecurityCriticalAttribute.
This attribute must be given to methods thats need full trust to execute code ( usually native code calls, unsafe code, graphics resources (wich usually needs unmanaged code etc.) ).

If methods are not granted full trust the Security Critical method raise an exception.

more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Color` from `System.Windows.Media` instead.